# Grab values from PHP string

Tags: php

I have a variable in my PHP script called `$url`

Here's an example of how I use it:

```
<?php 
$url = '/test/?utm_source=test&utm_campaign=test2&utm_medium=test3";
```

I'd like to have a PHP snippet that grabs the valus of `utm_source`, `utm_campaign` & `utm_medium`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: The phpmmanual is not just a useful resource, it's an essential one - http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php 

$url = "/test/?utm_source=test&utm_campaign=test2&utm_medium=test3";

$url_parsed=parse_url($url);
$query_params=[];
$query_parsed=parse_str($url_parsed['query'],$query_params);

echo $query_params['utm_source'].PHP_EOL.
    $query_params['utm_campaign'].PHP_EOL.
    $query_params['utm_medium'].PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with explode function:

```
<?php 
$url = "/test/?utm_source=test&utm_campaign=test2&utm_medium=test3";
$params = explode("=", $url);

$utmSource = explode("&", $params[1]);
$utmCampaign = explode("&", $params[2]);
$utmMedium = $params[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the function `parse_str()` is exactly what you are looking for. See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: Oddly, here's my code: 
`<?php
$url = "/test/?utm_source=test&UTM_campaign=test2&utm_medium=test3";
parse_str($url);
echo $utm_source."<br>";
echo $utm_campaign."<br>";
echo $utm_medium."<br>";`
This doesn't work. It only outputs the las one :(

Comment: Please don't share your feelings -its easy to check the facts (parse_str() is the wrong function for the data in the question,)

Comment: Funny how the accepted answer uses said function. Ah well.